# iOS - Core Data - Delete records using relationships and fetch request

Tags: ios, core-data, fast-enumeration, mutation

**Overview:**

I have an iOS project in which I am using core data

- I have an `Employees` entity and a `Department` entity.
- 1 department can contain many employees
- So the entity `Department` has a "to many" relationship with the entity `Employees`, the relationship is called `employees` and the reverse relationship is called `whichDepartment`

**Aim-1:**

I want to delete all the employees in a specific department

**Questions:**

a) is the following correct, or would it cause mutation or some problems ?

b) is this is the correct way to do it ?

**Pls Note** - `removeEmployees` is a method that was auto generated while creating the subclasses of the entities

```
- (void) deleteAllEmployeesForDepartment: (Department*) requestedDepartment
{
    [requestedDepartment removeEmployees:requestedDepartment.employees];
}
```

**Aim-2:**

- I want to delete the employees based on some condition
- I am deleting objects inside a fast enumeration loop for the fetched records

**Questions:**

c) Is the following correct, or would it cause some mutation ?

d) Is it like modifying the object in fast enumeration ?

e) Is there a better way to do it ?

**Pls Note** - `removeEmployees` is a method that was auto generated while creating the subclasses of the entities

```
- (void) deleteAllType1EmployeesWithDepartment: (Department*) requestedDepartment
{ 
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == %i AND whichDepartment ==%i", 1, requestedDepartment.departmentID];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *listOfEmployeesToBeDeleted = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];    

    for(Employees *currentEmployee in listOfEmployeesToBeDeleted)
    {       
       [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:currentEmployee];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in your `deleteAllEmployeesForDepartment:` this is fine to remove objects that way.

If in addition you want to delete the Employees objects from Core Data then you should add another rule, a *delete rule* set to *cascade*, meaning that when an `Employee` "losses" a `Department` (the relationship is broken, either by the `Department` being deleted, or the `Department` removing the `Employee`), it (the `Employee`) also is deleted.

Your second question is a little more interesting.

What I recommend is adding another method directly to the Department subclass of `NSManagedObeject`, you could call it - `clearEmployeesOfType:` passing a type number.

Since your `Department` has a reference to an `NSSet` of `Employees` via the to-many relationship you could use that `NSSet` and it's `filteredSetUsingPredicate:` method to filter out the ones you want.

The returning set can be used to message the `removeEmployees:` method on your `Department`, a little like the following (warning, code not tested).

```
- (void) clearEmployeesOfType:(NSUInteger)type
{ 
    NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.type == %d", type];
    NSSet * firedEmployees = [self.employees filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];

    [self removeEmployees:firedEmployees];
}
```

I would recommend this solution rather then loading objects and removing them one by one, whenever you can, rely on relationships and delete rules in Core Data.

Comment: thanks Daniel, I just tested the methods deleteAllEmployeesForDepartment and clearEmployeesOfType. Both these methods seem to be causing the `whichDepartment` (relationship) field to become NULL. I think the reason for this may be because internally fast enumeration or something similar might be used to loop through the NSSet, and deleting an object from the same set which is used in fast enumeration is causing this to happen. However fetch requests and looping through them and using deleteObject seems to work ok.